# Is "hails from X" only used for saying someone was born in X

Tags: idioms

I see "hails from Harvard" often, but the official definition says:

to come from or to have been born in a particular place:

but I have no idea what come from can mean. Too vague to make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you "come from" a place, it is where you have your home or where you have an affiliation, as in the case of the university in your example.

> Detective Jones comes from New York City's 5th Precinct.
>
> Dorothy comes from Kansas.

You can substitute "hails from" there.